# Optional group of keys

Tags: flowtype

I have to make two keys optional `index` and `remove` in an object. However if one is provided the other must be there. So its like this:

```
type Props = {
    isSettings: boolean,
} | {
    index: number,
    remove: $PropertyType<FieldProps, 'remove'> // (index: number) => void
}
```

Where the second object is optional. The above is not working, as it is not expecting `isSettings` in the 3rd object. But it is always required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard object types in Flowtype are objects defined to have *at least* the properties specified. This means that if you have a type like `{ isSettings: boolean }` you are saying only that that the object has an `isSettings` property that is a boolean. It is allowed to have other properties, it just has to know the type of `isSettings`.

This means that if you have a type

```
type Props = {
    isSettings: boolean,
} | {
    index: number,
    remove: (index: number) => void
};
```

then doing

```
var obj: Props = ...
if (obj.remove) {
  var n: number = obj.index;
}
```

will fail, because it doesn't prove anything, because you have not *prohibited* there being a `remove` property on both objects.

In order to refine an object type like this one, Flow needs to be told that each type has *exactly* the given set of properties. This is where Flow's [Exact object types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types) come in.

If you change your types to be

```
type Props = {|
    isSettings: boolean,
|} | {|
    index: number,
    remove: (index: number) => void
|};
```

then a snippet like

```
var obj: Props = ...
if (obj.remove) {
  var n: number = obj.index;
}
```

will work as expected, because the presence of `remove` means there *must* be a property called `index` that is a `number`.

Comment: Thank you very much for such an in-depth solution! And so fast!

Comment: I actually had a need to do this: `{| ...FieldProps, isSettings: boolean, |} | {|` there is a spread on the object inside there, it keeps getting highlighted as its not compatible. Is it possible to make a spread exact? Should I post another question for this?

Comment: Might be best to do another question. I don't know off the top of my head, but I do think these features are a little flakey when spread is involved.

Comment: Thanks logan I will create another soon :)

Comment: Hi there sir, the example is throwing errors in Flow :( - REPL https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AZRQE5YCGAtgJIAmoAvKAM6ECWAdgOYDcqmO+RZABWIEy9WqBYBXUgCMsBLohABjWC0agASgFEAYjtwAJcQHId+7UZNcQ6bFqyQi9ABYBBZSiZraSsKABvAB9QOywALjDYSC09A2MggF9QIL9QUAAKYNAmSnC+EgpqJNAAMkCQjGFRfMJCoRFSMSSAShtgVXUUUGJPbxZwhycsVw8vHzoA0J5w83iAGhy8k2J6SkgTUETkMNABAlgMMUnU9PSmelwsFC92ekGZWFhoEhZ5xBKQ4MQznJZKLAAD0GUlk8nevyIpFgADcIgxmOwPolFDDhKBYDIAFaDfaHY6BHKXa63Nj3QiSLCLKGwiIregmRasAHAgCM6RRiCYMQymKxADoaXCWoEfqA0QQJCDpHJJXQ+fzmUCuIkgA - for convencience I changed `remove` to `string`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. That example assigns _both_ sets of properties to the object, which is a violation of exact object typing. You'd want to remove the `isSettings:true`

Comment: Ah thanks Logan for that fast reply, I actually wanted to specify that `isSettings` must always be in all objects. And it is optional to have the `index, remove` keys.

Comment: You'd have to put `isSettings` on both sides of the `|`. https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1ABQE6wYDOoAvKAN4A+io9oAlsQMpYoqMB2A5sQFygARrFjQsAQy4AaRNQC+oalVoMmrdp14Dho8VNlruAEywAPQVwCuAWyFZ8hhviw3YANyyDiKfNx5y8gDcyO4S+KCwQgBWggREpBSU6mwc-gK+VljSoC5unvwA5BLEhTkm5vwAjPTBiIyQoAAUUdEAdHkeWACUVHSgYRFclrb2ERStbRVmIfJAA